# VerloopSdk integration with React-Native

Tags: react-native

Trying to integrate verloop with react-native using [react-native-sdk](https://github.com/verloop/react-native-sdk). Getting undefined when calling function VerloopSdk.showChat();

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import VerloopSdk from 'react-native-verloop-sdk';

export default class VerloopLiveChat extends Component {

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const clientId = "<YOUR COMPANY ID>"; // it is same as https://<YOUR COMPANY ID>.verloop.io
    await VerloopSdk.createAnonymousUserConfig(clientId);
    //or
    await VerloopSdk.createUserConfig(clientId, userId);

    //optional
    VerloopSdk.putCustomField(key, value);
    //optional
    VerloopSdk.setRecipeId(recipeId);
    //optional
    VerloopSdk.setUserEmail(email);
    //optional
    VerloopSdk.setUserPhone(phoneNumber);
    //optional
    VerloopSdk.setUserName(name);

    VerloopSdk.showChat();
}

render() {
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: Is there any code you have try or now?

Comment: How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)